# How to place label inside square node in vis.js

Tags: vis.js

As per the `vis.js` documentation position of the label is dependent on the node shape.

> The shape defines what the node looks like. There are two types of
>   nodes. One type has the label inside of it and the other type has the
>   label underneath it. The types with the label inside of it are:
>   ellipse, circle, database, box, text. The ones with the label outside
>   of it are: image, circularImage, diamond, dot, star, triangle,
>   triangleDown, hexagon, square and icon.

Is there any way I can position the label inside the sqaure node.

```
nodes: {
  shape: 'square',
  chosen: true,
  color: {
    highlight: {
      border: '#2B7CE9',
      background: '#fff'
    },
    hover: {
      border: '#2B7CE9',
      background: '#D2E5FF'
    }
  },
  font: {
    size: 9
  },
  borderWidth: 2
}
```

[image]

In box shape  label  will be inside but the problem is I am not to update the size of the node. Is there any way to do that?

[image]